# Stylesheet not loading correctly on mobile

Tags: css, mobile

I have just migrated my website to a new server. The website displays correctly on laptop. When I view the website on my mobile device the text does not display correctly (it worked fine on the previous server).

When I inspect the website using Chrome mobile viewer it is also correct and displays as it should using the correct media queries.

Any idea as to why it displays differently on an actual mobile device?

[The website URL](http://liftthebar.com)

Comment: Please specify how it's supposed to look and how it does instead - how are we supposed to know what's being displayed in an unintended way?

Comment: Have you tried opening the site in incognito mode on your mobile phone?  Chrome mobile does a nasty job of hanging onto things in cache.  Maybe it's trying to find a style sheet you had in a different place before or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

For all screens you have a *padding-left: 183px* . When your screen is smaller then 320px your padding-left of 183px returns.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 667px) and (min-device-width: 320px){
.header-txt h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
}
```

What you can do is either decrease your *min-device-width: 320px* or do another media query for targeting smaller devices. Something like *@media max-width(768px)* with *padding-left: 0* would work.